# Update ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project with ASP.NET Identity 2.0 and DB, created by ASP.NET Identity 1.0. I want to update my DB. I do the following actions:

1. Enable migrations:

> Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Web
>
> Checking if the context targets an existing database...
>
> Code First Migrations enabled for project Web.

2. Add Migration (My project has 2 connection strings, I select appropriate, with 'old' DB tables):

> Add-Migration -Name UpdateIdentity -ProjectName Web
>   -ConnectionStringName MainContext
>
> Scaffolding migration 'UpdateIdentity'.
>
> The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your
>   current Code First model. This snapshot is used to calculate the
>   changes to your model when you scaffold the next migration. If you
>   make additional changes to your model that you want to include in this
>   migration, then you can re-scaffold it by running 'Add-Migration
>   UpdateIdentity' again.

but it generates the following script:

```
public override void Up()
{
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AspNetRoles",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex");

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AspNetUserRoles",
        c => new
            {
                UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                RoleId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.RoleId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetRoles", t => t.RoleId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.UserId)
        .Index(t => t.RoleId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AspNetUsers",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                CompanyId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                SMSnumber = c.String(),
                FullName = c.String(),
                Email = c.String(maxLength: 256),
                EmailConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                PasswordHash = c.String(),
                SecurityStamp = c.String(),
                PhoneNumber = c.String(),
                PhoneNumberConfirmed = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                TwoFactorEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                LockoutEndDateUtc = c.DateTime(),
                LockoutEnabled = c.Boolean(nullable: false),
                AccessFailedCount = c.Int(nullable: false),
                UserName = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .Index(t => t.UserName, unique: true, name: "UserNameIndex");

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AspNetUserClaims",
        c => new
            {
                Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                ClaimType = c.String(),
                ClaimValue = c.String(),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.UserId);

    CreateTable(
        "dbo.AspNetUserLogins",
        c => new
            {
                LoginProvider = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                ProviderKey = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                UserId = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.LoginProvider, t.ProviderKey, t.UserId })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.UserId, cascadeDelete: true)
        .Index(t => t.UserId);

}
```

It tries to create tables from zero, but I need a script to modify. Why so and how to create correct scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF does a compare to the prior migration. If there is none, it compares the current models to an empty database. So what you need is to create an initial, codeless migration:

`add-migration MyStartPoint -IgnoreChanges`

Now the next migration will be the changes only. So in your case, if you can roll back to Identity 1, make this migration, update to Identity 2, add a 2nd migration then you will get what you need. See [here](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/EF/Migrations-Under-the-Hood).

Comment: it creates an empty migration

Comment: Yes, `-IgnoreChanges` tells EF to just capture the model with no Up() code. You do that before you change the models or upgrade Identity. Then `update-database` to apply it. Now, upgrade to Identity 2 and the 2nd migration will be a difference with the needed changes.